# How to compile boost libraries

Tags: software-compilation, gcc

I'm trying to compile boost libraries that I need for compiling and installing [Ocelot tracker](https://github.com/WhatCD/Ocelot) on the Raspberry Pi. I tried with libraries from `apt-get` but it doesn't work.

These are instructions for Ubuntu on x86 machine.

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
./b2 stage toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++11 threading=multi link=shared
sudo ./b2 install toolset=gcc cxxflags=-std=gnu++11 threading=multi link=shared
```

What do I have to change to compile it correctly on Raspberry Pi? I'm currently on Raspbian Jessie, but will change it if needed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It compiles with same commands, system realizes that platform is arm and adjusts accordingly. My problem was elsewhere.

Comment: Since your real problem was not the problem described in the question I've closed this.